# Best Practices of backing up HIVE Tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

We have our business data in Hive tables. The Hive tables is partitioned by year_week.Recently we had an issue where all of the weeks partitions data are lost(we are not sure how) and HIVE tables are not backup unfortunately. Now we are looking for best practice for backing up HIVE tables.

Comment: Cf. Cloudera BDR (licensed) and whatever similar tool HortonWorks has set up >> snapshot HDFS directories storing Hive datasets; backup Metastore, either via the API or directly via underlying DB native backup tool;  replicate the HDFS files (from stable snapshot) to another DR cluster -- or to cloud storage; release snapshot.

Comment: There is also a commercial backup solution for Hadoop (and Cassandra), altough I can't remember their new name (nor the old one).

Comment: @roh, replication = redundancy means high availability;  backup means ability to recover from disaster (building flooded, cloud provider down because of Russian attack, servers down because of ransomware, data lost because of "fat finger" maintenance, etc) even if RPO/RTO mean delays, costs, and some lost data. That's completely different. And Murphy's law asserts that a dropped partition will "skip trash" because it's how shit happens.

Comment: you are right @Samson Scharfrichter. Thanks

Comment: You need to backup your metastore as well... Not only the HDFS data. Run an export from Oozie or other scheduler https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ImportExport